# How to change multiple string occurances into one?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string that I receive from backend, like this:

```
Hello wolrd <br> <br> <br> I am <br><br> Uksz <br>.
```

Now, the amount of `<br>` is never constant - there can be one, or up to 5. How can I change all `<br>` that are next to each other with only one `<br>`? So that the above example would be:

```
Hello wolrd <br> I am <br> Uksz <br>.
```

Comment: Use a Regular Expression (regex) to filter duplicate entries?

Comment: @Roberrrt, can you show me how I can achive that using my example?

Comment: I'm a mess with regex. =( I suppose someone else can be of service though,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use this solution:

```js
var test = "Hello wolrd <br><br> <br> <br> <br> <br><br> I am <br><br> Uksz <br><br> <br><br> <br> <br> <br><br> <br> <br> <br><br><br>.";
var re = /(\<br\>)(\s*(\<br\>))+/gi;
var result = test.replace(re, "<br>");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Comment: @webmaster Your solution has following issues:-

- It always adds an unnecessary extra space at the end of <br>. e.g. "Hello <br>World" will be converted into "Hello <br> World".
- Also, the regex match and replace the single <br> as well. This will be an unnecessary performance lag.

Please check my solution below.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ranojit Banerjee, fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:-

```
var string = "Hello world <br> <br> <br> I am <br><br> Uksz <br>.";
var result = string.replace(/(\<br\>\s*)+(\<br\>)/g, '$2'); // your result string will return Hello world <br> I am <br>  Uksz <br>.
console.log(result);
```

This regex will remove the space in between br tags only.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```js
var yourString = "Hello wolrd <br>   <br> <br> I am <br><br> Uksz <br>.";
var pattern = /(<br>((\s)*(<br>))*)/gi;
console.log(yourString.replace(pattern, "<br>")); // returns "Hello wolrd <br> I am <br> Uksz <br>."
```

Note: this leaves whitespaces intact (before and after `<br>`).